# Can we write to two signals from a port map statement?

Tags: vhdl

This is perhaps more of a hypothetical VHDL question as opposed to a real-life/case study question.

Say I have a component declaration as follows...

```
component my_comp is
    port (
    A : in std_logic;

    --...other input/outputs

    B : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
);
end component my_comp;
```

And within the same entity containing `my_comp` i have the signals

```
signal my_comp_full_scale_output : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal my_comp_8_scale_output    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Is there a way which I can assign these two signals both the value of B in the `port map` statement of the component instantiation? Something like this maybe...

```
my_comp_isnt : my_comp
    port map (
    A => some_signal,

    -- other signal assignments

    B => my_comp_full_scale_output,
    B(9 downto 2) => my_comp_8_scale_output
);
```

Once again I stress that this is totally playing with VHDL's logic and I am not using this in any design!!! I do know that this can easily be done with an assignment of `my_comp_full_scale_output` to `my_comp_8_scale_output` outside of the component instantiation such as below and this is simply a sake of code for code's sake.

```
my_comp_isnt : my_comp
    port map (
    A => some_signal,

    -- other signal assignments

    B => my_comp_full_scale_output
);

my_comp_8_scale_output <= my_comp_full_scale_output(9 downto 2);
```

Comment: On Vivado simulator, you can't associate an output to 2 differents signals : ```ERROR: [VRFC 10-705] formal led_2 is already associated```

Comment: Why is `my_comp_8_scale_output <= my_comp_full_scale_output(9 downto 2);` so bad?

Comment: @Oldfart in case you have lots of similar assignments, i think it can get a bit confusing, e.g. dont think of `my_comp` as a computational block but as a form of memory map where each bit of `B` could mean a different setting for your system, (if i start to argue my own logic back to me) this is arguably where you would start to use aliases... e.g. `alias controlbit1 : std_logic is my_comp_full_scale_output(9);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

[1076-2008 - IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/servlet/opac?punumber=4772738) states:

> Each association element in an association list associates one
> actual designator with the corresponding interface element in the
> interface list of a subprogram declaration, component declaration,
> entity declaration, block statement, or package.

So you can only map it once.

Comment: Thanks! But damn, I think this could be a really cool feature if it were allowed.

Comment: Why not just create `my_comp_8_scale_output` to be an alias of `my_comp_full_scale_output(9 downto 2)`